# Defining lists and calling functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I am using Python 3. This is for a homework project for a class, but I'm not looking for something to do the problem for me! I was just wondering if someone could help point out exactly where I've gone wrong, or what I need to look into to make my code work.

```
def main():

    taxPayersList = []
    incomesList = []
    taxesList = []

    taxPayersList, incomesList = inputNamesAndIncomes(taxPayersList, incomesList)

    taxesList = calculateTaxes(incomesList)
    displayTaxReport(taxesList, incomesList, taxPayersList)


def inputNamesAndIncomes(taxPayersList, incomesList):
    print('Welcome to Xanadu Tax Computation Program')
    print('')
    confirmation = input('Do you have income amounts? y/n ')
    index = 0

    try:

        while confirmation == 'y' or confirmation == 'Y':
            taxPayersList[index] = input('Enter a tax payer name: ')
            incomesList[index] = float(input('Enter income amount: '))

            confirmation = input('Are there more income amounts? ')
            index += 1
    except:
        print('An error occurred. Please only enter numbers for income amount.')

    return taxPayersList, incomesList

def calculateTaxes(incomesList):

    index = len(incomesList)

    while index < len(incomesList):
        if incomesList[index] >= 0 and incomesList[index] <= 50000:
            taxesList[index] = incomesList[index] * .05

        elif incomesList[index] >= 50000 and incomesList[index] <= 100000:
            taxesList[index] = 2500 + ((incomesList[index] - 50000) * .07)

        elif incomesList[index] >= 100000:
            taxesList[index] = 6000 + ((incomesList[index] - 100000) * .09)

        index += 1

    return incomesList    


def displayTaxReport(taxesList, incomesList, taxPayersList):
    print('2018 TAX DUES FOR XANADU STATE')
    print('')
    print('Name\t\tANNUAL INCOME\tTAXDUE')
    for n in incomesList:
        print(taxPayersList,'\t\t',incomesList,'\t',taxesList)


main()
```

Right now, I can enter a name into the first input, but as soon as I hit enter it just prints out my error code and then print out the final function like below.

```
Welcome to Xanadu Tax Computation Program

Do you have income amounts? y/n y
Enter a taxpayer name: Susan
An error occurred. Please only enter numbers for income amount.
2018 TAX DUES FOR XANADU STATE

Name        ANNUAL INCOME   TAXDUE
```

I know this is a total mess but any help at all would be so appreciated!

Comment: you should avoid using `except:`. for this case, you should use `except ValueError:` as that is what will be raised if an invalid float is entered. `except:` will catch everything, and you won't be able to see other errors.

Comment: if you know the number of entries beforehand, use `[None]*number_of_entries`, Else use `append()` as mentioned in one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` for the line

```
taxPayersList[index] = input('Enter a tax payer name: ')
```

You didn't see it because you excepted all errors and didn't print them. I suggest using

```
name = input('Enter a tax payer name:')
taxPayersList.append(name)
```

etc. Note that I append it to the list. I also suggest a different strategy of handling errors.

Alternatively, you might wish to use a dictionary instead of using two lists, since you want to associate an income with a name,

```
name = input('Enter a tax payer name:')
income = float(input('Enter income amount:'))
incomes[name] = income
```

Comment: `raw_input` in Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just assign into a non-existant index for a list to add items to it:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a[0] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Instead you should look at using the `.append()` method for lists.

(The reason you aren't seeing the `IndexError` debugging details is because your `except` clause prevents it from being displayed. Bare `except` clauses are often considered an antipattern because they mask unexpected errors like this and make it harder to tell what went wrong - they catch *any* exception, not just ones due to bad user input.)